# How to check if a package is already installed on ubuntu?

Tags: macos, shell, ubuntu, xampp

I am downloading xampp server on ubuntu by `'wget'` command.
I would like to download it only if it's not installed on ubuntu.
How to check if xampp is already installed or not ?

```
dpkg -s xampp , I think this is not the right way.
```

Could you please let me know.

Comment: I could be out of line here: but if your OS is Ubuntu you don't need xampp. you can install PHP Apache MYSQl natively.. Also Known as a LAMP stack!

Comment: @Jason Joslin : Correct, I agree. But installing XAMPP  is advantageous as it's a single package, avoids installing individual packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -l xampp 
dpkg-query: no packages found matching xampp
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  Tried with xampp & lampp. Is there different string to check it ?

Comment: if you want to find package then you can use commad                                                        root@ubuntu:~# locate xampp

Comment: It just locates the location of file. It won't fetch from the  installed path.

Comment: I don't know bro what you want actually but you can try this one as well. All the default installation through wget stores in /usr/bin or /opt directory. You just go inside /usr/bin and opt directory and find xampp or lampp. if installed then you will defiantly find the files here.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely disagree that Xampp has advantages over LAMP if you are operating Ubuntu. Please try installing these:

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

`sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`

There you go. A full Lamp Stack without xampp.

Please know I have simply quoted this website:

> http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I am aware of LAMP. Since, XAMP is packaged and bundled together which I feel easy to install and use it. I don't think so major difference.